What tool to use to unscrew square head bolt?
Not possible to use a conventional wrench.
file:///var/folders/7p/ccwl5rr50vl9k5m55fl7hx380000gn/T/TemporaryItems/NSIRD_screencaptureui_GlZgwA/Screenshot%202024-09-04%20at%206.24.03%E2%80%AFPM.png

A local file reference doesn't work for the reset of us. Click Edit and then the "mountains and sun" icon and you can upload the image file.

Explanation: file:\\  means the resource is on your PC. https\\  means there's a resource that can be accessed through a web server.

An 8-point socket can be used to turn a square head bolt or nut. As a socket, it may be able to access fasteners that a conventional wrench cannot.

As can an adjustable wrench, or a crescent wrench of the right size.

Well, yes, but the question states "not possible to use a conventional wrench." One might reasonably expect that an adjustable wrench will be excluded for the same (unspecified) reasons for which a conventional wrench won't work.

True. We really need that photo to clarify the constraints.
